# PHP - String value of Key of Multidimensional Array inside nested foreach loops

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

I'm trying to get the string value of the key of the innermost array(s) However, `Food & Drink`, `Candy` & `Tea or Coffee Sets` just return as `Array`.

```
<?php

$categoryParents = array(

  'Food & Drink' => array(
      'Beverages' => array(
        'Energy & Sports Drinks',
        'Wine & Champagne'
      ),
      'Candy' => array(
        'Chewing Gum',
        'Lollipops',
        'Jelly Beans'
      ),
      'Candy Dishes',
      'Food Gifts',
      'Fruit',
      'Popcorn',
      'Pretzels',
      'Seeds',
      'Spices',
      'Tea Or Coffee Sets' => array(
        'Coffee',
        'Tea'
      ),
      'Water'
  )

);

foreach ($categoryParents as $pcat => $psubcats) {
  foreach ($psubcats as $psubcat) {
    if (is_array($psubcat) && sizeof($psubcat) > 0) {
      print_r($psubcat . " <-- parent test \n");
      foreach ($psubcat as $psub2cat) {
        print_r($psub2cat . " <-- sub \n");
      }
    } else {
      print_r($psubcat . "<-- parent \n");
    }
  }
}

?>
```

The Output of this script on my machine is as follows:

```
PHP Notice:  Array to string conversion in /Users/guy/Desktop/test-2.php on line 34

Notice: Array to string conversion in /Users/guy/Desktop/test-2.php on line 34
Array <-- parent test 
Energy & Sports Drinks <-- sub 
Wine & Champagne <-- sub 
PHP Notice:  Array to string conversion in /Users/guy/Desktop/test-2.php on line 34

Notice: Array to string conversion in /Users/guy/Desktop/test-2.php on line 34
Array <-- parent test 
Chewing Gum <-- sub 
Lollipops <-- sub 
Jelly Beans <-- sub 
Candy Dishes<-- parent 
Food Gifts<-- parent 
Fruit<-- parent 
Popcorn<-- parent 
Pretzels<-- parent 
Seeds<-- parent 
Spices<-- parent 
PHP Notice:  Array to string conversion in /Users/guy/Desktop/test-2.php on line 34

Notice: Array to string conversion in /Users/guy/Desktop/test-2.php on line 34
Array <-- parent test 
Coffee <-- sub 
Tea <-- sub 
Water<-- parent
```

This is as close as I've gotten this script to work. I'm pretty sure I'm missing a chunk of conditional logic in the nested foreach loops, I just can't think through it anymore. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write this fragment so to print array key

```
foreach ($psubcats as $k => $psubcat) {
    if (is_array($psubcat) && sizeof($psubcat) > 0) {
      print_r($k . " <-- parent test \n");
```

[**demo**](https://eval.in/931672)